# Running coupling constants QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

I am very confused and probably understanding the concepts of [renormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization) wrongly: If the running coupling constant is a real experimentally observable quantity and the change with scale has a physical interpretation as "vacuum polarization", how can it get independent of the scale if we could sum up all orders of perturbation theory?

Comment: The perturbation is a power series of the coupling constant and the loop (i.e. $\hbar}$). Not energy.